# Getting only one result instead of multiple results

Tags: python, python-2.7

Program

```
f=open('something.txt'.'r')
lines=f.readlines()
for read in range(0,len(lines)):
    c=lines[read]
    d=lines[read]
    if c[0:4]=='ATOM':
        AX1=float(c[32:38])
        AY1=float(c[40:46])
        AZ1=float(c[48:54])
        A1=c[77]
    if d[0:6]=='HETATM':
        HX1=float(d[32:38])
        HY1=float(d[40:46])
        HZ1=float(d[48:54])
        H1=d[77]
    distance=math.sqrt((HX1-AX1)**2+(HY1-AY1)**2+(HZ1-AZ1)**2)
    print 'Distance b/w ',A1,' and ',H1,'',distance
```

file will be like:

```
ATOM      1  N   ALA A   4      15.660  74.786  38.080  1.00 29.54           N  
ATOM      2  CA  ALA A   4      15.546  74.666  39.526  1.00 27.64           C  
ATOM      3  C   ALA A   4      16.833  74.137  40.145  1.00 25.88           C  
ATOM      4  O   ALA A   4      17.852  73.890  39.500  1.00 24.05           O  
.
.
.
ATOM   6048  OXT ALA A 780      21.816  67.407  16.290  1.00 13.41           O  

HETATM 6050  C1  GLC A2002       5.415  71.753  22.098  1.00 21.40           C  
HETATM 6051  C2  GLC A2002       3.948  71.252  22.308  1.00 21.24           C  
HETATM 6052  C3  GLC A2002       3.065  71.966  21.254  1.00 20.81           C  
HETATM 6053  C4  GLC A2002       3.266  73.512  21.425  1.00 20.10           C  
HETATM 6054  C5  GLC A2002       4.737  73.893  21.253  1.00 21.47           C  
HETATM 6055  C6  GLC A2002       4.967  75.396  21.466  1.00 22.53           C  
HETATM 6056  O1  GLC A2002       6.224  71.231  23.190  1.00 22.04           O  
HETATM 6057  O2  GLC A2002       3.902  69.831  22.018  1.00 21.46           O  
HETATM 6058  O3  GLC A2002       1.682  71.659  21.493  1.00 21.68           O  
HETATM 6059  O4  GLC A2002       2.509  74.212  20.404  1.00 17.87           O  
HETATM 6060  O5  GLC A2002       5.516  73.179  22.244  1.00 21.76           O  
HETATM 6061  O6  GLC A2002       6.361  75.746  21.230  1.00 24.18           O
```

I want to calculate values using the above mentioned formula. It should compare the ATOM-1 to all HETATM and ATOM-2 to all HETATM and goes on.

But i am getting result for only last ATOM and all HETATM

Result

```
Distance b/w  O  and  C  17.9335824921
Distance b/w  O  and  C  19.2422912617
Distance b/w  O  and  C  19.925505715
Distance b/w  O  and  C  20.1926162247
Distance b/w  O  and  C  18.9312388924
Distance b/w  O  and  C  19.3521031932
Distance b/w  O  and  O  17.4740790888
Distance b/w  O  and  O  18.963047118
Distance b/w  O  and  O  21.2256606258
Distance b/w  O  and  O  20.8804518629
Distance b/w  O  and  O  18.2881409662
Distance b/w  O  and  O  18.2427943583
```

Comment: Is this the real code? `open('something.txt'.'r')` is invalid.

Comment: You're going through all the ATOMs line by line before you hit any HETATM, so the last ATOM's data is saved before you start getting HETATM, and you compare that ATOM to all HETATM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with this block here:

```
lines=f.readlines()
for read in range(0,len(lines)):
    c=lines[read]
    d=lines[read]
```

You're only looping once, and assigning `c` and `d` to the same line at a time.

Instead, you want to loop once for `c`, and once for `d`. The more pythonic way to do this is looping directly over `lines`, instead of `range(0, len(lines))`.

```
lines=f.readlines()
for c in lines:
    for d in lines:
        # the rest of your code
```

Also, as pointed out by [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092177/getting-only-one-result-instead-of-multiple-results/35092273#comment57906331_35092177), you aren't doing anything with `A1` and `H1` when there's not a match, so you may inadvertently compare old data from a previous loop. Be sure to skip those cases, perhaps with a `continue` in an `else` statement after the failed `if`:

```
if c[0:4]=='ATOM':
    AX1=float(c[32:38])
    AY1=float(c[40:46])
    AZ1=float(c[48:54])
    A1=c[77]
else:
    continue
```

Comment: `import glob
     import math
    f=open('data.txt','r')
    q=f.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(q)):
     b=q[i]
     a=b.rstrip()
     a=a.lower()
     chain=a[4]
     f=open('/home/iitm/Bond_Distance/{}.txt'.format(a[0:4]), 'r')
     lines=f.readlines()
     for c in lines:
      if c[21]=={}.format(a[4]):`                                                       When i try this getting error like this ,help me                                                          
  `File "bond_length.py", line 13, in <module>
   if c[21]=={}.format(a[4]):
   IndexError: string index out of range`